# saving or opening file without overwriting the data using QFiledialog

Tags: python-3.x

Is there a way where in we can save a file and if the file exists open it for appending data without over writing it using QfileDialog in Python.

```
self.jsonPath, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, 'Save File'QtCore.QDir.homePath() +  "/TrackDetails.json", "JSON Files(*.json)")
    self.path_MVEdit.setText(self.jsonPath)
```

This statement always asks me to overwrite my file if it already exsts.

Answer (score 0):

this can be done by simply adding DontConfirmOverwrite to your save dialog

```
self.jsonPath, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, 'Save File', QtCore.QDir.homePath() +  "/TrackDetails.json", 
                        "JSON Files(*.json)",None ,QtWidgets.QFileDialog.DontConfirmOverwrite)
```